# 1 Table Cell with Same Width as Multiple Others Beneath It in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, 2d-games

I am just looking for a clear answer to a problem that I have been having while using LibGDX. I have been working on an Android game in LibGDX and have come across the problem of creating the UI layout. I want one button to have the same width as a few others located beneath it.[Something just like this rough plan.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1rca.png) The edges are the boundries of the screen.

Sorry about the link this is my first question. I have tried to work with different cell widths, expanding, and filling on the X axis with little success as the bottom cells move to the end of the cell on the top.

`table.add(settingsButton).width(Value.percentWidth(0.5f, table));`

[The problem I have been having.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcqxJ.png)

I would just appreciate a little help tackling this problem as I am relatively new to LibGDX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in this way :

```
// w and h according to resource size (In my casee button width is 297 pixel)
float w=1000;
float h=600;

stage=new Stage(new StretchViewport(w,h));

Skin skin=new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/glassy-ui.json"));

Table table=new Table();
table.setFillParent(true);
table.defaults().pad(10);
stage.addActor(table);

table.add(new TextButton("PLAY",skin)).colspan(3);
table.row().padTop(5);
table.add(new TextButton("SHOP",skin));
table.add(new TextButton("SELECT",skin));
table.add(new TextButton("SETTINGS",skin));
table.row().padTop(10);

 stage.setDebugAll(true);
 Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

And the output is :

[image]